# Delete multiple line text file with bulk list using php

Tags: php

I want to delete multiple lines from a text file with bulk list.

My base file `file.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

List of lines to delete `bulkdel.txt`

```
line2
line4
```

Desired output:

```
line1
line3
line5
```

How can I do this? I only have a comparison script but it doesn't delete:

```
$b = file('bulkdel.txt');
$f  = file('file.txt');

foreach($f as $line) {
    foreach($b as $bulk) {
        if (strpos($line, $bulk) !== false) {
            echo $line .'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried anything, because we dont just write code for you

Comment: update.........

Comment: You were missing a `)` after `$bulk` in the second `for` loop in your example, presumably it was a copy/paste typo...if not...you have a typo that I fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could do this.

You could easily do what you are doing and `unset` the key you don't need.

```
foreach($f as $key => $line) {
    foreach($b as $bulk) {
        if (strpos($line, $bulk) !== false) {
            unset($f[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also create a function to pass by reference and modify the array using `unset()` via searching for a value with `array_search()`:

```
function bulkRemove(&$f,$b)
    {
        foreach($b as $line) {
            $search =   array_search($line,$f);
            if($search !== false)
                unset($f[$search]);
        }
    }

bulkRemove($f,$b);
```

You can also use a closure with `array_map()` and remove empty with `array_filter()`

```
$array = array_filter(array_map(function($v) use ($b) {
        if(!in_array($v,$b))
            return $v;
    },$f));
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you are using the option with `array_search()`, this:

```
$f  =   array('line1','line2','line3','line4','line5');
$b  =   array('line2','line4');
function bulkRemove(&$f,$b)
    {
        foreach($b as $line) {
            $search =   array_search($line,$f);
            if($search !== false)
                unset($f[$search]);
        }
    }

bulkRemove($f,$b);

echo count($f);
print_r($f);
```

Gives you:

```
3

Array
(
    [0] => line1
    [2] => line3
    [4] => line5
)
```

Comment: output = line1
line3
line5line1
line3
line5line1
line3
line5

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using all of these?

Comment: i try with array search function

Comment: Where are you putting it? All it does is loop through your `$b` array once and searches each line then removes it from the `$f` array. There is no way that will output 3 times unless you put it in a loop.

Comment: i get output using echo foreach ($f as $ff) {
   echo $ff .'<br>';
  }

Comment: After the function, try `echo count($f);`. What does it say?

Comment: That doesn't even make sense...you should add more code because none of what you are getting for output makes any sense,

Comment: sorry typo output == 5 5

Comment: You have it in at least two loops since it echoed 5 twice, however you still have something going on there because it should have said 3, unless there are empty lines that are in the array. Either way it's repeating not due to what I did